# Grouping variable products in packs with predetermined variations (Color, Size) and quantity

Tags: woocommerce, product

All of my products are variable products with **2 attributes (Size, Color)**, and sell my products in bulk. My objective is to group the variable products in **"Packs"** with pre-determined size+qty. The user selects only the color and the pack type (Pack#1/Pack#2/Pack#3). There is a single price for all variations.

[image: Product setup]

Comment: Did you tried [WPC Grouped Product for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpc-grouped-product/) plugin?

Comment: Hi, @LoicTheAztec Thank you for your suggestions and prompt reply. Can this be programmed instead of installing a separate plugin?

Comment: Yes everything is possible, but this is a real development that requires skills and time… So it's better to find a plugin if you are not a developer with a real budget for it.

Comment: Hi, @LoicTheAztec checked the recommended plugin, yet it is not serving our intended purpose. What would be the rough estimate for the custom development of my exactrequirement?